# API SDK TA PUSH ZKTeco

Tags: java, api, push, zkemkeeper

Tengo un dispositivo MB360 de ZKTeco con conexión ADMS, el cual si se está conectando correctamente al servidor ADMS por método PUSH, pero al momento de que este se conecta se adelanta 13 horas a la zona horaria de China, al parecer este no esta tomando los parámetros de la zona horaria del servidor es cual está en colombia.

Implemente este método al momento de que el dispositivo solicitá la conexión.

```
private String registryDeviceATT(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        String retValue = "404";
        String sn = request.getParameter("SN");
        if (Db.devMap.get(sn) != null)//has registered
        {
            String registrycode = (String) Db.devMap.get(sn).get("registrycode");
            retValue = "RegistryCode=" + registrycode;
            System.out.println("\t has been registed，register code：" + registrycode);
        } else//not registered
        {
            String randomString = getRandomString(10);
            String datas = getStreamData(request);
            Map<String, String> dataMap = parseStringToMap(datas);
            dataMap.put("ATTLOGStamp", "9999");
            dataMap.put("OPERLOGStamp", "0");
            dataMap.put("ATTPHOTOStamp", "0");
            dataMap.put("TransFlag", "TransData AttLog OpLog AttPhoto EnrollUser ChgUser EnrollFP ChgFP FPImag FACE UserPic BioPhoto");
            dataMap.put("ErrorDelay", "60");
            dataMap.put("Delay", "30");
            dataMap.put("transTimes", "00:00;14:05");
            dataMap.put("TransInterval", "1");
            dataMap.put("Realtime", "1");
            dataMap.put("Encrypt", "1");
            dataMap.put("ServerVer", "2.2.14");
            dataMap.put("TimeZone", "-0500");
            Map<String, Object> optionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            optionsMap.put("options", dataMap);
            optionsMap.put("registrycode", randomString);
            Db.devMap.put(sn, optionsMap);
            retValue = "RegistryCode=" + randomString;
            System.out.println("\t not registered,go to regist，return register code：" + randomString);
        }
        return retValue;
    }
```

pero el dispositivo continua con la hora y fecha desconfigurada.

si alguien por favor cuenta con el SDK PUSH para TA de ZKteco le agradeceria enormemente

Answer (score 1):

Se debe de enviar la zona horaria al momento de conectar el dispositivo

```
private String registryDeviceATT(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String retValue = "404";
    String sn = request.getParameter("SN");
    if (Db.devMap.get(sn) != null)//has registered
    {
        String registrycode = (String) Db.devMap.get(sn).get("registrycode");
        //String registrycode = (String) Db.devMap.get(sn).get("options");
        retValue = "RegistryCode=" + registrycode;
        System.out.println("\t has been registed，register code：" + registrycode);
    } else//not registered
    {
        retValue = "GET OPTION FROM: " + sn + "\n"
                + "ATTLOGStamp=0\n"
                + "OPERLOGStamp=0\n"
                + "ATTPHOTOStamp=0\n"
                + "TransFlag=TransData AttLog OpLog AttPhoto EnrollUser ChgUser EnrollFP ChgFP FPImag FACE UserPic BioPhoto\n"
                + "ErrorDelay=60\n"
                + "Delay=30\n"
                + "transTimes=00:00;14:05\n"
                + "TransInterval=1\n"
                + "Realtime=1\n"
                + "Encrypt=1\n"
                + "ServerVer=2.2.14\n"
                + "TimeZone=-5";
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tuve un problema similar y la forma en la que lo resolví es no enviando el TimeZone al final de la respuesta, al parecer la última línea es descartada.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).